# Can tasks.rake within lib/tasks see other ruby files within lib? [Rails]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I keep getting an error where it's not able to 'see' a class sitting in my lib from the rake task.

i.e I have my rake task:

```
task task_name: :environment do

    object=ClassA.new
    ModuleA.read(object)
end
```

And both `moduleA.rb` and `classA.rb` are in `lib`, and the rake task is at `lib/tasks.rake`

The error I get when I try to run `rake task_name` is:

```
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant ClassA
```

I tried to require the module/class but I end up with:

```
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- lib/classA
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pull in the files. Remember that your path needs to be relative to the directory the rakefile is in.

```
load './ClassA.rb' 
load './moduleA.rb'
require 'ClassA'
```

The require is redundant but may be needed if your `classA.rb` file is really complex. Also note that your naming style doesn't match up with the default Inflector in Rails but if you are using just pure ruby this shouldn't matter although you should follow conventions.

Answer (score 0):

If your `lib/` folder is loaded by Rails, you shouldn't need anything to call other libs, as the Rails autoloader will do the job for you.

By default, Rails doesn't include the `lib/` folder, so you have to add this line to your `config/application.rb` file :

```
config.autoload_paths << File.join(config.root, 'lib')
```

It should work, then.